# Cannot modify managed objects outside of a write transaction Realm Android

Tags: android, android-fragments, realm

I am facing problems in updating the realm object. I am having 4 fragments. I am carry forwarding the value from one fragment to the next. There are total 16 fields. 1st fragments contains 4 and so on. First I am saving the object of 4 first four fields with this method:-

```
public static <T extends RealmObject> void InsertRecordinRealm(final Class<T> clazz, final T passedObject, final Integer integerd) {
    Realm realm = getRealmInstance();
    realm.executeTransaction(new Realm.Transaction() {
        @Override
        public void execute(Realm realm) {
            realm.copyToRealmOrUpdate(passedObject);
        }
    });
    realm.close();
}
```

Now, I am getting the Values from the first fragment to the second fragment by using this method:-

```
public static <T extends RealmObject> T GetRecordById(Class<T> clazz, Integer id) {
    RealmQuery<T> queryForUsern = getRealmInstance().where(clazz).equalTo("RealmId", 1);
    T recordByid = queryForUsern.findFirst();
    return recordByid;
}
```

Here I am getting the Object Correctly. But when i am updating the object with the values of Second fragment i am getting this error "Cannot modify managed objects outside of a write transaction"

In Second fragment i am Updating the Object with:-

```
public static <T extends RealmObject> void UpdateRecordinRealmByID(final T passedObject, final Class<T> clazz, final Integer Id) {
        Realm realm = getRealmInstance();
        realm.executeTransaction(new Realm.Transaction() {
            @Override
            public void execute(Realm realm) {

                RealmQuery<T> queryForUsern = 
                getRealmInstance().where(clazz).equalTo("RealmId", 1);
                T recordByid = queryForUsern.findFirst();
                recordByid = passedObject;
                realm.insertOrUpdate(recordByid);
            }
        });
        realm.close();
    }
```

Help will be appreciated! Thanks in Advance

Comment: What are you trying to do with `recordByid = passedObject` ? That makes the whole query pointless.

Comment: How Should I Query it?

Comment: You can only modify a managed RealmObject in a write transaction. So however you are trying to modify `passedObject`, that is where your code actually fails...

Comment: Whatever you assign to `recordByid` before, is voided by afterwards assigning `recordByid = passedObject`.

Answer (score 3):

Well, In my case I was updating the value of the realm object outside of `realm.executeTransaction {}`, as soon as I moved the code inside this `realm.executeTransaction {}` the error is gone.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of

```
RealmQuery<T> queryForUsern = 
            getRealmInstance().where(clazz).equalTo("RealmId", 1);
```

do this:

```
RealmQuery<T> queryForUsern = realm.where(clazz).equalTo("RealmId", 1);
```

Explanation:
The `executeTransaction()` is already given a realm instance with the open transaction. You have to use that realm instance. In your code, you fetched a 'new' realm instance, with no open transaction, thus the error.